# CGridview Conditional display related model data

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to filter product record in gridview by category_id

I have three table

> ProductMst(product_id,name)
>
> CategoryMst(category_id,category_nme)
>
> PromotedUserProduct(category_id,product_id) ====> junction table

### productMst model rules like this

```
   public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'categoryMsts' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'CategoryMst', 'promoted_user_product(user_product_id, category_id)'),

    );
}
```

### My controller code like this

```
         $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
    $categoryCondition=array();
      if(isset($_GET['category_id']) && $_GET['category_id']!==""){     
        $categoryCondition=array('select'=>false,
                'condition'=>'categoryMsts.category_id=1',
                'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN ');
    }

    $criteria->with=array(
            'categoryMsts'=>$categoryCondition);



    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('UserProductDtl',array(
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>$pagesize,
            ),
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    $this->render('index',
        array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

I am not able to filter the record, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$categoryCondition=array(
    'select'=>false,
    'condition'=>'category_id=:category_id',
    'params'=>['category_id'=>$_GET['category_id'],
    'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN '
);
```

Comment: thanks for reply... i have tried your query but still not working

Comment: actually i m not getting any error.... but it will show all product withouth filter.................... here i m copy link that give more detail about my tlbe struture.... i have same table structure like... post, post_category, category.. now i want to find post for particular category.                                                                    http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr